# how to unstack (or pivot?) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, stack, pivot

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
datelisttemp = pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=3, freq='D')
s = list(datelisttemp)*3
s.sort()
df = pd.DataFrame({'BORDER':['GERMANY','FRANCE','ITALY','GERMANY','FRANCE','ITALY','GERMANY','FRANCE','ITALY' ], 'HOUR1':[2 ,2 ,2 ,4 ,4 ,4 ,6 ,6, 6],'HOUR2':[3 ,3 ,3, 5 ,5 ,5, 7, 7, 7], 'HOUR3':[8 ,8 ,8, 12 ,12 ,12, 99, 99, 99]}, index=s)
```

This gives me:

```
Out[458]: df

             BORDER  HOUR1  HOUR2  HOUR3
2014-01-01  GERMANY      2      3      8
2014-01-01   FRANCE      2      3      8
2014-01-01    ITALY      2      3      8
2014-01-02  GERMANY      4      5     12
2014-01-02   FRANCE      4      5     12
2014-01-02    ITALY      4      5     12
2014-01-03  GERMANY      6      7     99
2014-01-03   FRANCE      6      7     99
2014-01-03    ITALY      6      7     99
```

I want the final dataframe to look something like:

```
             HOUR  GERMANY  FRANCE  ITALY
2014-01-01   1     2        2       2     
2014-01-01   2     3        3       3
2014-01-01   3     8        8       8 
2014-01-02   1     4        4       4
2014-01-02   2     5        5       5
2014-01-02   3    12       12      12
2014-01-03   1     6        6       6
2014-01-03   2     7        7       7
2014-01-03   3    99       99      99
```

I've done the following but I'm not quite there:

```
df['date_col'] = df.index

df2 = melt(df, id_vars=['date_col','BORDER'])  
#Can I keep the same index after melt or do I have to set an index like below?
df2.set_index(['date_col', 'variable'], inplace=True, drop=True)
df2 = df2.sort()
```

df

```
Out[465]: df2

                         BORDER   value
date_col   variable                 
2014-01-01 HOUR1           GERMANY   2
           HOUR1           FRANCE    2
           HOUR1           ITALY     2
           HOUR2           GERMANY   3
           HOUR2           FRANCE    3
           HOUR2           ITALY     3
           HOUR3           GERMANY   8
           HOUR3           FRANCE    8
           HOUR3           ITALY     8
2014-01-02 HOUR1           GERMANY   4
           HOUR1           FRANCE    4
           HOUR1           ITALY     4
           HOUR2           GERMANY   5
           HOUR2           FRANCE    5
           HOUR2           ITALY     5
           HOUR3           GERMANY  12
           HOUR3           FRANCE   12
           HOUR3           ITALY    12
2014-01-03 HOUR1           GERMANY   6
           HOUR1           FRANCE    6
           HOUR1           ITALY     6
           HOUR2           GERMANY   7
           HOUR2           FRANCE    7
           HOUR2           ITALY     7
           HOUR3           GERMANY  99
           HOUR3           FRANCE   99
           HOUR3           ITALY    99
```

I thought I could unstack df2 to get something that resembles my final dataframe but I get all sorts of errors. I have also tried to pivot this dataframe but can't quite get what I want.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We want values (e.g. `'GERMANY'`) to become column names, and column names (e.g. `'HOUR1'`) to become values -- a swap of sorts.

The `stack` method turns column names into index values, and 
the `unstack` method turns index values into column names.

So by shifting the values into the index, we can use `stack` and `unstack` to perform the swap.

```
import pandas as pd

datelisttemp = pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=3, freq='D')
s = list(datelisttemp)*3
s.sort()
df = pd.DataFrame({'BORDER':['GERMANY','FRANCE','ITALY','GERMANY','FRANCE','ITALY','GERMANY','FRANCE','ITALY' ], 'HOUR1':[2 ,2 ,2 ,4 ,4 ,4 ,6 ,6, 6],'HOUR2':[3 ,3 ,3, 5 ,5 ,5, 7, 7, 7], 'HOUR3':[8 ,8 ,8, 12 ,12 ,12, 99, 99, 99]}, index=s)

df = df.set_index(['BORDER'], append=True)
df.columns.name = 'HOUR'
df = df.unstack('BORDER')
df = df.stack('HOUR')
df = df.reset_index('HOUR')
df['HOUR'] = df['HOUR'].str.replace('HOUR', '').astype('int')
print(df)
```

yields

```
BORDER      HOUR  FRANCE  GERMANY  ITALY
2014-01-01     1       2        2      2
2014-01-01     2       3        3      3
2014-01-01     3       8        8      8
2014-01-02     1       4        4      4
2014-01-02     2       5        5      5
2014-01-02     3      12       12     12
2014-01-03     1       6        6      6
2014-01-03     2       7        7      7
2014-01-03     3      99       99     99
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. It has helped me better understand stack/unstack. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Using your `df2`:

```
>>> df2.pivot_table(values='value', index=['DATE', 'variable'], columns="BORDER")
BORDER               FRANCE  GERMANY  ITALY
DATE       variable                        
2014-01-01 HOUR1          2        2      2
           HOUR2          3        3      3
           HOUR3          8        8      8
2014-01-02 HOUR1          4        4      4
           HOUR2          5        5      5
           HOUR3         12       12     12
2014-01-03 HOUR1          6        6      6
           HOUR2          7        7      7
           HOUR3         99       99     99

[9 rows x 3 columns]
```

There is still a bit of cleanup to do if you want to convert the index level "variable" into a column called "HOUR" and strip out the text "HOUR" from the values, but I think that is the basic format you want.