# Python: Rows to Columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

looking to transform non-numerical data from rows to columns. I am new in python, checked pivot, stack, unstack pandas method but didn't work, need suggestion here.

Image contains actual row wise data and for understanding i have added required format.

Thanks for the help !!

[Data Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT7J8.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include both the input data and the expected output **as text** in your question.

Comment: Sure @Roy2012,will add

Comment: How this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640399/how-to-unstack-or-pivot-in-pandas doesn't solve your problem?