# How to reshape a pandas dataframe with boolean values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of biological samples that can show an event at Day 1, Day 2 or Day 3. My dataframe looks like that :

```
    Cell#   Event
0   0   Day 3
1   1   Day 2
2   2   Day 2
3   3   Day 1
4   4   Day 3
5   5   Day 3
6   6   Day 2
7   7   0
8   8   Day 1
9   9   Day 2
```

It means that Cell#0 showed event at Day3 and Cell#7 did not show the event.

I would like to reshape it in order to have this kind of dataframe :

```
    Cell#   Day 1   Day 2   Day 3
0   0   0   0   1
1   1   0   1   1
2   2   0   1   1
3   3   1   1   1
4   4   0   0   1
5   5   0   0   1
6   6   0   1   1
7   7   0   0   0
8   8   1   1   1
9   9   0   1   1
```

It means that while event has not happened, value is 0, but as it has happened, value turns to 1 until the end.

I have been struggling with unstack ([how to unstack (or pivot?) in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640399/how-to-unstack-or-pivot-in-pandas)) and pivot but I cannot find the solution...

Please, could you let me know if you have any clue in order to solve this issue ?

Kindly !

Comment: If any answer helps, close the question by accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
pd.concat([df.drop(['Event'], axis=1),pd.get_dummies(df['Event'])], axis=1).drop('0',axis=1)
```

Or

```
df.assign(**pd.get_dummies(df['Event'])).drop(['Event', '0'],axis=1)
```

---

**using unstack**:

```
df.assign(k=1).set_index(['Cell#','Event'])['k'].unstack().reset_index(drop=True).drop('0',axis=1).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Hello ! Function get_dummies was the key to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: @chalbiophysics: You can use unstack also. I have given you the code for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `get_dummies`

```
out = df.join(df.pop('Event').replace('0',np.nan).str.get_dummies())
```

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed it's working. It was harder than I thought !

Comment: I don't understand the role of `str` accessor here. Wasn't it possible to get the dummies directly on the return series of `replace` method without using `str`?

Comment: @ashkangh most of the time the 0 here is str '0' , so dummies  will include one more column which is 0

Comment: Sorry for again asking questions. But you already replaced those str`0` with `nan` values.

Comment: @ashkangh str here is a function tool ~ not 'str' ~