# partially transpose a dataframe (exchange subset of the columns and rows)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe below:

```
station      date  A  B  C
     NY  2019-1-1  0  1  4
     NY  2019-1-2  3  9  3
     WN  2019-1-1  3  7  6
     WN  2019-1-2  0  1  2
```

How can I change it to the following format?

```
station METRIC  2019-1-1  2019-1-2
     NY      A         0         3
     NY      B         1         9
     NY      C         4         3
     WN      A         3         0
     WN      B         7         1
     WN      C         6         2
```

I am not sure whether I should use stack/unstack/melt/pivot/pivot_table...

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve). In particular share text/code not pictures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to unstack (or pivot?) in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640399/how-to-unstack-or-pivot-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stack`/`unstack`:

```
(df.set_index(['station', 'date'])
   .rename_axis('METRIC', axis=1)  # set name for future A/B/C column
   .stack()                        # move A/B/C as rows
   .unstack('date')                # move date as columns
   .rename_axis(None, axis=1)      # remove "date" name from index
   .reset_index()
)
```

or `T`+`stack`:

```
(df.set_index(['station', 'date'])
   .T
   .rename_axis('METRIC', axis=0)
   .stack('station')
   .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
   .swaplevel()
   .reset_index()
)
```

input:

```
  station      date  A  B  C
0      NY  2019-1-1  0  1  4
1      NY  2019-1-2  3  9  3
2      WN  2019-1-1  3  7  6
3      WN  2019-1-2  0  1  2
```

output:

```
  station METRIC  2019-1-1  2019-1-2
0      NY      A         0         3
1      NY      B         1         9
2      NY      C         4         3
3      WN      A         3         0
4      WN      B         7         1
5      WN      C         6         2
```